# Combining select distinct and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, union

This is my SQL query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT dest 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE exp = ? 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT exp 
    FROM messages 
    WHERE dest = ?
```

With this query, I get all the messages I've sent or received. But in my table `messages`, i have a field `timestamp`, and i need, with this query, add an order by timestamp... but how ?

Comment: If there are multiple entries, which timestamp do you require?

Comment: i just need to order my messages with the newest first

Comment: Your query does not return all the messages you have sent or received.  It returns all the people that you have communicated with, with no duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, but i need to have one with whom I spoke last in first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (   SELECT
           col1 = dest,
           col2 = MAX(timestampCol)
        FROM
            messages 
        WHERE 
            exp = ? 
        GROUP BY 
            dest
        UNION 
        SELECT
            col1 = exp,
            col2 = MAX(timestampCol)
        FROM
            messages 
        WHERE 
            dest= ? 
        GROUP BY 
            exp
    ) tbl
ORDER BY col2
```

This should return only one row per `distinct` `exp` / `dest` though I'm sure this could probably be done without a union; The `GROUP BY` will only get the most recent one.

**Updated SQL:** Given that it is possible for an `exp` on one record to equal a `dest` on the same or another record.

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN exp = ? THEN dest ELSE exp END AS col1  
    ,MAX(timestampCol) AS col2
FROM 
    messages 
WHERE 
    exp = ? 
    OR dest = ?
GROUP BY 
    (CASE WHEN exp = ? THEN dest ELSE exp END)
ORDER BY 
    MAX(timestampCol) DESC;
```

You might want to consider adding an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with some dummy data to allow users to better help you.

Comment: No idea what i need to do with [col1] and [col2].

Comment: `[col1]` and `[col2]` are just names I've given to the columns given the use of `UNION` it clarifies which columns will be returned. `[col1]` is the distinct entry you were returning in your query, `[col2]` is the timestamp column. If you don't want to return the timestamp column you could just `SELECT DISTINCT [col1]` instead of `SELECT *`

Comment: Ok so.. You have an error in your SQL syntax ^^ Phpmyadmin don't like your [col1]

Comment: It's SQL Server syntax for holding column names (a bad habit as it's not universal), I have removed these now. you might need to change it from the format `**columnname** = **data**` to a format similar to `**data** AS **columnname**` or use single quotations if your column names have white space but I'm not absolutely certain of the exact syntax.

Comment: Okay, now there is a problem, i dont get unique col1,  I get all possible combinations of timestamp

Comment: I have added further SQL though as I've stated in my question you might want to create an SQL Fiddle with some dummy data as currently it's difficult to be certain what precisely you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without a `union`:

```
SELECT (case when exp = ? then dest else exp end), timestamp
FROM messages 
WHERE exp = ? or dest = ?;
```

Then to get the most recent message for each participant, use `group by` not `distinct`:

```
SELECT (case when exp = ? then dest else exp end) as other, max(timestamp)
FROM messages 
WHERE exp = ? or dest = ?
group by (case when exp = ? then dest else exp end)
order by max(timestamp) desc;
```

Comment: @ClémentAndraud . . . Here is a simple SQL Fiddle that shows that both are syntactically correct SQL (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c72625/2).  This is a simplified table structure with `0` replacing `?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT dest AS Column1, timestamp AS Column2
    FROM messages 
    WHERE exp = ? 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT exp AS Column1, timestamp AS Column2
    FROM messages 
    WHERE dest = ?
) tbl
ORDER BY Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you in getting records order by timestamp

```
SELECT tbl.mailId, Max(timestampColumn) MostRecentDate
 FROM
    (
     SELECT exp AS mailId, Max(timestampCol) AS timestampColumn
     FROM Employeeatd 
     WHERE dest = ?  
     GROUP BY exp 
UNION 

     SELECT Dept AS abc, Max(timestampCol) AS timestampColumn
     FROM Employeeatd 
     WHERE exp = ?   
     GROUP BY Dept
    ) tbl
 GROUP BY mailId
 ORDER BY Max(timestampColumn) desc
```